# required info about j/xfs

Tags: java, cen-xfs

What exactly is j/xfs in simple terms?

Comment: You can't have it "exactly" *and* in "simple terms". You can have one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEN/XFS

> J/XFS - a Java implementation of the
>   CEN XFS API
>
> CEN/XFS or XFS provides a
>   client-server architecture for
>   financial applications on the
>   Microsoft Windows platform, especially
>   peripheral devices such as EFTPOS
>   terminals and ATMs which are unique to
>   the financial industry.