# is anybody have experience of using J/XFS?

Tags: java, cen-xfs

i have to use j/XFS implementations with my java application. and i dont have any idea of what j/xfs is? on google also i found only one small 15page document. so can anybody give me some links?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026409/required-info-about-j-xfs - that lists a bunch of links, and explains what it is.

Answer (score 0):

To add a few comments, the idea behind the J/XFS is to make you application independen of specific financial device (printers, check readers etc).

Also check out [www.dynasty.es](http://www.dynasty.es), they have a commercial platform based on J/XFS with huge number of drivers and administrative tools. (I'm not affiliated with them, but they seem to be the only company I know that offer such products).